# Excel VBA to copy range as picture and save on path for MACOS

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, module

Hello i have made a excel vba code which copy range (A1:O25) as picture and then paste it on a path as JPG. path is written in R1 cell every time code will get the path from R1 but problem is that the module is correctly working on windows but it is not working on MACOS it gives an error
"Error 70 at runtime:
Consent denied"
What is the solution of this?

```
Sub Export()
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long

Set oWs = ActiveSheet
Set oRng = oWs.Range("A1:O25")

oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = oRng.Width
lHeight = oRng.Height

Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)

oChrtO.Activate
Dim pathaddress As String
pathaddress = Range("R1").Value
With oChrtO
.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
.Height = oRng.Height
.Width = oRng.Width
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.Export pathaddress & oChrtO.name & ".jpg"
End With
oChrtO.Delete
End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with `"\"` vs `"/"` in path name?  Or path is missing? Or no right to write into it?

Answer (score 0):

**check pathaddress = E:\data**

```
Sub Export()
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
    Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long
    
    Set oWs = ActiveSheet
    Set oRng = oWs.Range("A1:O25")
    
    oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    lWidth = oRng.Width
    lHeight = oRng.Height
    
    Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
    
    oChrtO.Activate
    Dim pathaddress As String

    pathaddress = Range("R1").text
    With oChrtO
    .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .Height = oRng.Height
    .Width = oRng.Width
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export pathaddress & oChrtO.name & ".jpg"
    End With
    oChrtO.Delete
    End Sub
```